# DDL statements are not allowed in transactions during setup:upgrade in 2.3.5p2 to 2.4.0

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4

during `setup:upgrade` get an error

> Module '`Magento_PurchaseOrder`':
>
> Unable to apply data patch
> `Magento\PurchaseOrder\Setup\Patch\Data\InitPurchaseOrderSalesSequence`
> for module `Magento_PurchaseOrder`.
> Original exception message: DDL
> statements are not allowed in transactions

Comment: did you tried to manually delete generated folder and then run di:compile and then s:up?

Answer (score 0):

DDL statements won't work in setup patch because now you need to use declarative schema(db_schema.xml) to run DB queries (i.e, table creation).

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/

Comment: Considering this is an error in a Magento module. The error must be in a different place

Answer (score -1):

You have to update your Magento B2B module, you can use these commands below, but first, change the composer.json to have the most updated version.

```
"magento/extension-b2b": "^1.2",
```

Then run:

```
composer update -vvv
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:enable
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Comment: Hi  @Rafael Thank you for the answer. I changed the b2b version in my setup and run composer update. but it shows no new updates. and I run setup:upgrade command the issue is not resolved.

Comment: This doesn't work...